# How to detect when rotated rectangles are colliding each other

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, collision-detection, rectangles

After seeing this question many times and replying with old (and not usable) code I decided to redo everything and post about it.

**Rectangles** are defined by:

- `center` : `x` and `y` for his position (remember that 0;0 is TOP Left, so Y go down)
- `size`: `x` and `y` for his size
- `angle` for his rotation (in deg, 0 deg is following axis OX and turn clockwise)

**The goal** is to know if 2 rectangles are colliding or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will use Javascript in order to demo this (and also provide code) but I can be done on every language following the process.

**Links**

- [Final Demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/ArthyFiciel/pen/YzybzaV)
- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ArthurGerbelot/rect-collide)

**Concept**

In order to achieve this we'll use corners projections on the other rectangle 2 axis (X and Y).
The 2 rectangles are only colliding when the 4 projections on one rectangles hit the others:

- Rect Blue corners on Rect Orange X axis
- Rect Blue corners on Rect Orange Y axis
- Rect Orange corners on Rect Blue X axis
- Rect Orange corners on Rect Blue Y axis

[image: 3 concept previews]

**Process**

**1- Find the rects axis**

Start by creating 2 vectors for axis 0;0 (center of rect) to X (OX) and Y (OY) then rotate both of them in order to get aligned to rectangles axis.

[Wikipedia about rotate a 2D vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions)

```js
const getAxis = (rect) => {
  const OX = new Vector({x:1, y:0});
  const OY = new Vector({x:0, y:1});
  // Do not forget to transform degree to radian
  const RX = OX.Rotate(rect.angle * Math.PI / 180);
  const RY = OY.Rotate(rect.angle * Math.PI / 180);

  return [
     new Line({...rect.center, dx: RX.x, dy: RX.y}),
     new Line({...rect.center, dx: RY.x, dy: RY.y}),
  ];
}
```

Where Vector is a simple `x,y` object

```js
class Vector {
  constructor({x=0,y=0}={}) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  Rotate(theta) {
    return new Vector({
      x: this.x * Math.cos(theta) - this.y * Math.sin(theta),
      y: this.x * Math.sin(theta) + this.y * Math.cos(theta),
    });
  }
}
```

And Line represent a slop using 2 vectors:

- origin: Vector for Start position
- direction: Vector for unit direction

```js
class Line {
  constructor({x=0,y=0, dx=0, dy=0}) {
    this.origin = new Vector({x,y});
    this.direction = new Vector({x:dx,y:dy});
  }
}
```

Step Result

[image]

**2- Use Rect Axis to get corners**

First we want extend our axis (we are 1px/unit size) in order to get the half of width (for X) and height (for Y) so by adding then (or inverse of them) we can get the all corners.

```js
const getCorners = (rect) => {
  const axis = getAxis(rect);
  const RX = axis[0].direction.Multiply(rect.w/2);
  const RY = axis[1].direction.Multiply(rect.h/2);
  return [
    rect.center.Add(RX).Add(RY),
    rect.center.Add(RX).Add(RY.Multiply(-1)),
    rect.center.Add(RX.Multiply(-1)).Add(RY.Multiply(-1)),
    rect.center.Add(RX.Multiply(-1)).Add(RY),
  ]
}
```

Using this 2 news methods for Vector:

```js
  // Add(5)
  // Add(Vector)
  // Add({x, y})
  Add(factor) {
    const f = typeof factor === 'object'
      ? { x:0, y:0, ...factor}
      : {x:factor, y:factor}
    return new Vector({
      x: this.x + f.x,
      y: this.y + f.y,
    })
  }
  // Multiply(5)
  // Multiply(Vector)
  // Multiply({x, y})
  Multiply(factor) {
    const f = typeof factor === 'object'
      ? { x:0, y:0, ...factor}
      : {x:factor, y:factor}
    return new Vector({
      x: this.x * f.x,
      y: this.y * f.y,
    })
  }
```

Step Result

[image]

**3- Get corners projections**

For every corners of a rectangle, get the projection coord on both axis of the other rectangle.

Simply by adding this function to Vector class:

```js
  Project(line) {
    let dotvalue = line.direction.x * (this.x - line.origin.x)
      + line.direction.y * (this.y - line.origin.y);
    return new Vector({
      x: line.origin.x + line.direction.x * dotvalue,
      y: line.origin.y + line.direction.y * dotvalue,
    })
  }
```

*(Special thank to Mbo for [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61956906/2929632) to get projection.)*

Step Result

[image]

**4- Select externals corners on projections**

In order to sort (along the rect axis) all the projected point and take the externals projected points we can:

- Create a vector to represent: Rect Center to Projected corner
- Get the distance using the Vector Magnitude function.

```js
  get magnitude() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  }
```

- Use the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to know if the vector is facing the same direction of axis or inverse (when signed distance is negative)

```js
getSignedDistance = (rect, line, corner) => {
  const projected = corner.Project(line);
  const CP = projected.Minus(rect.center);
  // Sign: Same directon of axis : true.
  const sign = (CP.x * line.direction.x) + (CP.y * line.direction.y) > 0;
  const signedDistance = CP.magnitude * (sign ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Then using a simple loop and test of min/max we can find the 2 externals corners. The segment between them is the projection of one Rect on the other one axis.

Step result

[image]

**5- Final: Do all projections hit rect ?**

Using simple 1D test along the axis we can know if they hit or not:

```
const isProjectionHit = (minSignedDistance < 0 && maxSignedDistance > 0
        || Math.abs(minSignedDistance) < rectHalfSize
        || Math.abs(maxSignedDistance) < rectHalfSize);
```

[image]

**Done**

Testing all 4 projections will give you the final result. =] !!

[image: 3 concept previews]

Hope this answer will help as many people as possible. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Nice work. Does you approach work for "greek cross" rectangle intersection and full inclusion?

Comment: OK. Have you seen "separating axes algorithm"? Perhaps you might find some similarities and ideas. [Article](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf)

Comment: I saw it during the time I worked on that answer. But it look way more complex (and complete too) than mine ^^

Comment: this is super cool, but how would I go about writing a function that takes 2 DOM elements (that could be rotated) and returns a boolean if they overlap or not?

Comment: @MikeWagz the same way, you just have to compute the position, width and height of your 2 DOM elements then run this to know if they overlap